# Creating a script for Windows 11 to gzip some files using 7-zip then move and replace them in another folder

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, script, zip

I have the following directory structure:
Parent Folder: Project
Children of Project: data, rawData

Inside of rawData I have: index.html, settings.html, user.html, script.js, style.css and other files.

I need to write a script for Windows 11, that "gzips" only the above mentioned files, moves and replaces them from `rawData` to `data`.

I have tried the following:

#### A bat script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Assuming the script is located inside the "rawData" folder
set "DataPath=..\data"

for %%f in (index.html settings.html user.html script.js style.css) do (
    set "SourceFile=%%f"
    set "DestinationFile=!DataPath!\%%f"
    set "GzippedFile=!DataPath!\%%f.gz"

    if exist "!SourceFile!" (
        echo Gzipping !SourceFile!...
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tgzip "!GzippedFile!" "!SourceFile!" > nul
        
        if exist "!GzippedFile!" (
            echo Moving !GzippedFile! to !DestinationFile!...
            move /y "!GzippedFile!" "!DestinationFile!"
        ) else (
            echo Error gzipping !SourceFile!
        )
    ) else (
        echo !SourceFile! not found.
    )
)

echo Script completed.
exit /b 0
```

#### A PowerShell script:

```shell
# Set the paths relative to the script's location
$ScriptDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$RawDataPath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptDirectory -ChildPath "..\rawData"
$DataPath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptDirectory -ChildPath "..\data"

# List of files to gzip and move
$FilesToProcess = @("index.html", "settings.html", "user.html", "script.js", "style.css")

# Specify the path to 7-Zip executable
$SevenZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Loop through the files
foreach ($file in $FilesToProcess) {
    $SourceFile = Join-Path -Path $RawDataPath -ChildPath $file
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path $DataPath -ChildPath $file
    $GzippedFile = Join-Path -Path $DataPath -ChildPath "$file.gz"

    if (Test-Path $SourceFile) {
        Write-Host "Gzipping $SourceFile..."
        & $SevenZipExe a -tgzip "$GzippedFile" "$SourceFile"
        Copy-Item -Path $GzippedFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Force
        Remove-Item -Path $GzippedFile -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "$SourceFile not found."
    }
}

Write-Host "Script completed."
```

[This is what I have in `C:\Program Files\7-Zip`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNAC9.png)

#### Neither scripts do anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the directory structure and files by pasting the output of suitable `tree` and `dir` commands. How exactly do you start your script? Comment or remove the `@echo off` and show the output from running the script.